# fillplots module in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

Does anybody know about module **fillplots**  (http://fillplots.readthedocs.org)? I've successfully installed it but when I run some simple code from http://fillplots.readthedocs.org/en/latest/examples.html

```
from fillplots import plot_regions
plotter = plot_regions([
    [(lambda x: x ** 2,),  # x ^ 2 > 0 and
     (lambda x: x + 5,)],  # x + 5 > 0
])
```

nothing happens. How I can see that picture? The documentation of the package is quite poor, and I don't know what else I should do. Is there any other ways to plot the region that is the solution of a given system of inequalities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you import pyplot beforehand

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

then after you've called plotter you can do

```
plt.show()
```

and the plot will show.